# how to capture image from doc scanner app and show in imageview in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to capture image in android phone, but before capturing i wish to show user by which app to proceed further. My goal is to give user the list of apps which can click photo, but currently only camera photo is showing. Please guide me resolving this issue.
I am trying to capture image from doc scanner and then upload it from my app.

```
 public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

    Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();
    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    try {

        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent , 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, 
            res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (outputFileUri != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            }
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
    for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
        if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
            mainIntent = intent;
            break;
        }
    }
    allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new 
    Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
}

 public Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri() {

    Uri outputFileUri = null;
    try {

        File getImage = getExternalFilesDir("");
        if (getImage != null) {
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "profile.png"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outputFileUri;
}

 myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (checkCameraPermission()) {

                   
                        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), 1);
                 

                } 

            }
        });
```

Calling code:

```
     startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), 1);
```

Comment: `am trying to capture image in android phone` Well that is not done by Intent.ACTION_PICK but by using a CAMERA intent where the user can select the Camera app from a list of available Camera apps. The camera app will then capture a picture.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the comments. Currently when i use camera intent its not showing other apps hence not be able to get other apps to click a picture.

Comment: If there is only one camera app on your device or when you once made one default, you will not see the others any more. Why do you say 'click' instead of 'take'?

Comment: @blackapps there are 4 apps installed. also none of them has set camera for default. Basically i want to use doc scanner app to click pictures and upload them using my apis.

Comment: `there are 4 apps installed.` What kind of apps? Camera apps? Show your intent for taking a picture with the Camera please in a new code block. That action_pick makes no sense you know. And answer my remarks to the point please.

Comment: The whole time already it looks to me that you mess up "picking an image from the gallery"and "taking a picture with a camera app". Please elaborate.

Comment: @blackapps `What kind of apps?` doc scanner, b612 and 2 similar apps. I have made code correction and have replaced `action_pick`. As mentioned in the question i am looking for solution `on taking a picture with app other than camera app`

Comment: @blackapps for more simple way , i am just finding a way to capture an image using doc scanner app and not the default camera app and show into the imageview.

Comment: Well put that in the subject of your post and again in the first lines of your post. You are confusing the whole time now.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question too. Please guide me resolving my issue.

Comment: Which docscanner app? Give link to the playstore please. And you should start that scanner. Find out which action to use to start such apps. Mail the developers of the app how to.

Comment: @blackapps any other way than mailing the developers ?